# where is the file containing the Route class located in Laravel?

Tags: file, class, laravel, directory

I would like to see what kind of methods are in the class Route in Laravel, where do I need to go to find the class file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php
```

I recommend you to use an IDE or a code editor that supports PHP, like PHPStorm or Sublime Text.

I personally use *Sublime Text 3* with the *PHP Companion* package, so with a simple key the editor can find the original reference for me.

Answer (score 2):

A much more convenient way to find this kind of information is available at https://laravel.com/api/5.2/